# How asio deal with SIGPIPE?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Asio has code to ignore SIGPIPE which is in Signal_init.hpp, however there is a macro warp it in io_service.hpp:

```
#elif defined(__sun) || defined(__QNX__) || defined(__hpux) || defined(_AIX) \
  || defined(__osf__)
```

I compile in Ubuntu found the macro doesn't enabled, so `std::signal(Signal, SIG_IGN);` haven't been called.

However, when I write to an closed socket by asio, it can report EPIPE error by boost::system::error_code which in complete handler. According to [libc doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sending-Data.html#Sending-Data):

> In this case, send generates a SIGPIPE signal first; if that signal is
> ignored or blocked, or if its handler returns, then send fails with
> EPIPE.

How asio set with SIGPIPE let process to ignore it? Does asio do some special on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply tell the OS you want `SIGPIPE` ignored.

Asio has the code to do that here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/boost/asio/detail/signal_init.hpp

Strangely (?) it is only included on old-fashioned UNIX:

```
#if defined(BOOST_ASIO_WINDOWS) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
# include <boost/asio/detail/winsock_init.hpp>
#elif defined(__sun) || defined(__QNX__) || defined(__hpux) || defined(_AIX) \
  || defined(__osf__)
# include <boost/asio/detail/signal_init.hpp>
#endif
```

You can simply do this yourself:

```
#include <csignal>

// ...
std::signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

Or you can use the Asio signal-set class:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/signal_set.hpp>
#include <iostream>

boost::asio::io_service svc;
boost::asio::signal_set ss(svc);

static void ignore_signal(boost::system::error_code ec, int /*signal*/) {
    if (!ec) ss.async_wait(ignore_signal);
    // std::cout << "\n" << ec.message() << "\n";
}

int main() {
    ss.add(SIGPIPE);
    ss.add(SIGINT);
    ss.async_wait(ignore_signal);
    svc.run();
}
```

Comment: I'm curious how asio deal with that. It doesn't ignore SIGPIPE, haven't use MSG_NOSIGNAL. But when I continue write to an disconnected socket, there is no SIGPIPE at all!